Carrying dry lentils in checked/carry on luggage?
I will be traveling by plane to Pakistan in about a week
Can I carry uncooked, dry lentils in either the checked luggage or the hand carry?

What are the origin and destination of the flight?

I'm going ask the obvious question.  Lentils are a common product found pretty well everywhere.  Why do you feel the need to bring your own rather than buy locally?  (and eating them also implies being somewhere you can cook them).

surely you can just get lentils wherever you're flying to.

As implied in André's answer, are they commercially packages?

@jcaron i am going to Pakistan

One of your tags is airport security. If you focus solely on security you can board a plane with dry lentils and/or also carry them in your hold luggage.
However, in many countries they won't pass the customs check in case they are discovered. That includes all the countries in the Southern Common Market (including flights between those countries). In the United States you must declare them at customs and it is "generally allowed".

Do you have a source for that? Commercially packed dried beans/legumes with no insect infestation are usually "safe" and are allowed even into strict countries like Australia.

Neither are crystal clear:
https://www.gub.uy/ministerio-relaciones-exteriores/comunicacion/publicaciones/manual-para-retorno/manual-para-retorno/ingreso-alimentos
https://www.gov.br/receitafederal/pt-br/assuntos/aduana-e-comercio-exterior/viagens-internacionais/guia-do-viajante/entrada-no-brasil/proibicoes-restricoes
If it's vacuum packed they can easily pass, if they are dried is a grey area.

@lambshaanxy in many cases, at the very least they should be declared, so they can be inspected and will then be approved (or not). But as hinted to in the comments to the question: why bother? It’s not like it’s something exotic and hard to find.

Im going to Pakistan
